# GraphUI where is it installed?

Tags: applications

I have installed it, but can't find it?

and I need to "point to it"

searching for GraphUI comes back empty?

***later edit***

OK, so I worked out that it being flatpak app it is located at:

```
/home/username/.local/share/flatpak/app/com.github.artemanufrij.graphui
```

but how do I point to it? for another application to use it?

Comment: OK, so I worked out that it being flatpak app it is located at /home/username/.local/share/flatpak/app/com.github.artemanufrij.graphui but

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know whether it is the fact that it is flatpak?

or whether it is because GraphUI is not the same as Graphviz

but GraphUI did not work for me (using it with FreeCAD)

ended up installing "proper" Graphviz using terminal (and it all works fine...)

```
sudo apt install graphviz
```

*GraphUI is NOT Graphviz so if you need Graphviz (like me) don't bother with GraphUI*